# Codeigniter 3 - Unique session ID not being generated (Except on Firefox)

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am Using CI 3.0.6 and i have ran into a very strange problem . When i print out the all_userdata on the browser , it only shows the below output on Firefox , for rest all the browsers (mobile,phone,tablets), it only shows the **__ci_last_regenerate** variable . 
if i print out the below :

```
echo '<pre>';            
print_r($this->session->all_userdata()); exit;
```

Below is what i am getting on firefox :

```
Array
(
    [__ci_last_regenerate] => 1462123135
    [uniq_session_id] => 6bcd0f6a162a5d17cbdc8a884aa510f7
)
```

But on all other browsers , below is the output :

```
Array
(
    [__ci_last_regenerate] => 1462123073
)
```

I have autoloaded the session library and the driver as well in autoload.php .

Please let me know how to tackle this strange problem or is it something i am doing wrong .

Comment: its not possible if you are doing it in the right way can you should the code where you have generated the session for that